# Can't install Visual Studio Community

Tags: visual-studio

Photos : I do not know hot to change language so I put meaning in image descriptions ["Error sorry we can not perform installation"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgLoR.png) ["we can not find..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3upT.png) 
Problem : I can't install Visual Studio after my computer lagged during an update, so it basically lagged then I had to reset the PC and Visual Studio was kind of uninstalled.

I checked the default trouble shooting page and I tried out what was written, but it happened again.

Comment: I wish I had a magic wand but alas... we're going to need at least some sort of information besides "can't install"...

Comment: ok then I added photos